# collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath: does not get called

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a `UITableview`.  One of the `UITableViewCell's` is a `UICollectionview` with instance name "amenityView".  The `UICollectionViewDelegate` and the `UICollectionViewDataSource` are set in the `storyboard` as shown below.  The following methods get called and the data is populated as expected.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[image]

However, the methods below didn't get called when I select the `UICollectionViewCell` contained in the `UICollectionView`.  What have I missed?

```
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

UPDATE:
 return YES in this method `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:` will invoke the below two methods.  At least that's what was missing on my part.  Hope this will help some body...
[image]

Comment: is ["`.allowsSelection`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionView/allowsSelection) for your collection view set to YES?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann.  Thanks for your response.  ".allowsSelection" is set to "YES".

Comment: does the table view cell it's sitting in allow user interaction or selection of the cell itself?

Comment: the `UICollectionView` is smaller than the table view cell.  When I select the area outside the `UICollectionView` but inside the table view cell the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets called.  So yes the selection of the cell works.

Answer (score 1):

Does the table view's didSelectRowAtIndexPath get called? If so, the table view may be intercepting the touches and not passing them through to the collection view inside. I've never done the solution you are trying to do, but the collection view is inside a scroll view, and it may not be easy to pass the touch info along to the collection view in a way that makes sense, so you may need to disable tapping on the table view cell in order for the collection view to respond to touches.